# Automorphism group of central extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group wtih center $Z$. Let us consider the exact sequence $1\to Z\to G\to H:=G/Z\to 1$. Then can we describe $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ in terms of $\mathrm{Aut}(Z)$ and $\mathrm{Aut}(H)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, the quaternion group and the dihedral group of order $8$ have isomorphic centers (cyclic of order $2$) and isomorphic quotients by centers (isomorphic to Klein group), but their automorphism group are very different. (Not even the same order.)